# How to access list with nested maps with Cassandra Java Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am having trouble with getting a list including maps with `Cassandra Java Driver`.

For below version:

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> myList = state.getList(5, TypeTokens.mapOf(Integer.class, Integer.class));
```

The error is like:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed: Line 3: TypeTokens cannot be resolved"
```

And for version like below:

```
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> myList = state.getList(5 , Map.class);
```

The error is like:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed: Line 3: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map> to List<Map<Integer,Integer>>
```

And for last version like below:

```
List<Map> myList = state.getList(5, Map.class);
```

The compiler does not complain, but when I execute the aggregation the error is like:

```
FunctionFailure: Error from server: code=1400 [User Defined Function failure] message="execution of 'my_keyspace.count_min_udf[count_min_udt, int, int, text]' failed: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<map<int, int>> <-> java.util.Map]"
```

`state` is a UDT defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE count_min_udt(
  n int,
  m int,
  p bigint,
  hash_a list <bigint>,
  hash_b list <bigint>,
  values list<frozen <map<int, int>>>
);
```

Am I using them wrong? I'd appreciate some help

Comment: any specific reason for not using object mapper?

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit, I am new to Cassandra and I don't know about object mapper (I'll check it out though). What's wrong with my idea above? I want to just define a UDA using my UDF using my UDT, but I cannot compile my UDF.

Comment: ah, that's UDF - it wasn't clear from question. Have you tried to use full class name for  `TypeTokens` ? Although it may still not available, as UDFs are executed in limited sandbox. Also, if you're new to Cassandra, you need to be very careful with UDFs

Comment: Sorry, if I made an unclear question. I'll update it asap. Do you mean like:
List<Map<Integer, Integer>> myList = state.getList(5, com.datastax.driver.core.TypeTokens.mapOf(Integer.class, Integer.class));

Comment: Error: Line 5: The type com.google.common.reflect.TypeCapture cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: I am experimenting on Cassandra 3.11.6 and DSE 6.8.0 though.

Comment: I can't say out of the head, it needs experimentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
https://community.datastax.com/questions/3939/how-can-i-access-nested-collections-with-the-java.html